# Parameterizing the construction of a Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

By using this Python code (I'm working with Python 3.6):

```
length = 4
overall = [["row" + str(length + 1)] +
           [1.0] + [0.0] * (length - 1)]

for i in range(1, length):
   overall  += [["row" + str(i + length + 1)] +
                [0.0] * i + [1.0] + [0.0] * (length - (i + 1))]
```

I obtain the following list of lists:

**OUTPUT 1:**

```
overall = [['row5', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           ['row6', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           ['row7', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
           ['row8', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Now, I'd like to parametrize the piece of code above.

Given a parameter, for example, `n_repetitions = 3`, I'd like to obtain:

**OUTPUT 2:**

```
overall = [['row5', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           ['row6', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           ['row7', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
           ['row8', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

where, in each "row", the initial "group" made of 4 numerical one-element lists has been repeated `n_repetitions` times (`3`, in this example).

Which is a good way to do that in an automatic way (e.g.: by using a for loop, a list comprehension, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to confirm.

I follow your code

Output:

```py
overall = [['row5', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
           ['row6', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
           ['row7', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 
           ['row8', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

What do you hope?

```
overall = [["row5"], [1], [0], [0], [0],
           ["row6"], [0], [1], [0], [0],
           ["row7"], [0], [0], [1], [0],
           ["row8"], [0], [0], [0], [1]]
```

this ?

```py
length = 4
n_repetitions = 3
arr = [1.0] + [0.0] * (length - 1)
overall = [["row" + str(length + 1)] + arr * n_repetitions]

for i in range(1, length):
    _ = [0.0] * i + [1.0] + [0.0] * (length - (i + 1))
    overall += [["row" + str(i + length + 1)] + _ * n_repetitions]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use list comprehension + list addition/multiplication like so:

```
overall = [['row5', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           ['row6', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           ['row7', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
           ['row8', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

overall = [[row[0]] + row[1:]*repeat for row in overall]
```

Answer (score 0):

overall is a list of lists

```
    type(overall)
    list
```

in matrix terms, this is your ID matrix without the first column:

```
    id =[l[1:] for l in overall]
```

and this is your label columns:

```
    labels = [[l[0]]  for l in overall]
```

you can then isolate the first element of each list and repeat the rest:

```
    n_repetitions = 3
    result = [[l[0]] + l[1:]*n_repetitions for l in overall]
    result
```

```
[['row5', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 ['row6', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 ['row7', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 ['row8', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```